# Laravel 5: Redirect Not Working on Password Reset

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to override Laravel's default function for resetting passwords. Before I go ahead with resetting the password, I want to dynamically set $redirectTo based on certain user information, so that the user is properly redirected to a different page based on said info. However, when I go try to go through with it I end up at a completely white page with the path ".../password/reset". The user's password is being properly reset, but the redirect isn't working as intended.

My code is referenced below. What am I doing wrong?

**ResetPasswordController.php**

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
    {

        use ResetsPasswords;

        protected $redirectTo;

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->middleware('guest');
        }

        public function resetPasswordByUser(Request $request, Users $users)
        {
                $user = $users->findUserByEmail($request->input('email'));

                if ($user->case == 1) {
                    $this->redirectTo = '/case1';
                } elseif ($user->case == 2) {
                    $this->redirectTo = '/case2';
                } elseif ($user->case == 3) {
                    $this->redirectTo = '/case3';
                }

                $this->reset($request);

            }
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();

.......

Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@resetPasswordByUser');
```

Comment: Try using protected $redirectPath = '/somewhere' instead $redirectTo

Comment: Tried it. Current result is still the same, unfortunately.

Comment: make a dd('Here!') inside the method redirectPath() of the class vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php  to ensure that the process is coming to the method that makes the redirection

Comment: Did that, and the method is being called. Based on the logic I tried creating a method redirectTo(), which is being called but still isn't properly redirecting. Also trying to see if I can call the routes set up in web.php, to no success so far.